# Why can the integral of a holomorphic function be approximated by a polygon?

Tags: complex-analysis

In class, the lecturer proved the Cauchy-Goursat theorem for triangles and then claimed that by approximating a simple closed curve with a polygon, the general case followed. How would one show that the integral over a simple closed curve can be approximated arbitrarily well with a polygon and that such a polygon can be decomposed into triangles?

Comment: The curves which are allowed in Cauchy-Goursat are precisely the rectifiable curves: the ones that can be approximated arbitrarily closely by polygons. Proof by definition. :)

Comment: You want to use uniform continuity to argue that the line integral over the original curve and the line integral over the approximating polygon are very close.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip The lecturer defined a curve to be a continuous function $C:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and stated the theorem for simple closed curves which were also differentiable with a non-vanishing derivative. Is this equivalent to being rectifiable?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I was able to complete the proof using your suggestion.

Comment: @user109360: It implies rectifiability, but is not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to approximate the closed curve itself, which is done simply by approximating small pieces of the curve by line segments.  Same basic idea as approximating the area under a curve by rectangles, and same type of rationale for why you can make the approximation arbitrarily good.

Decomposing into triangles is intuitively obvious, and is done in the same way you would have learned in high school geometry.  Just draw some polygons and decompose in the obvious way.  Technical details are a bit of a pain.